# docker vieux/sshfs permission denied

Tags: docker, sshfs

1. I use vieux/sshfs to create a volume

```
docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions vieux/sshfs
docker volume create  -d vieux/sshfs   -o sshcmd=usfo@192.168.1.1:/swarm-study/web/data  -o password='123' sshvolume
```

2. I create a user on container :usfo 
   Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian
COPY sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y php7.0 php7.0-mysql
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN groupadd -g 1000 usfo
RUN useradd  -u 1000 -g 1000 usfo

COPY index.php /var/www/html/index.php
RUN mkdir /autorun
COPY autorun.sh /autorun/autorun.sh
RUN chmod 755 /autorun/autorun.sh
RUN mkdir /html-data
CMD ./autorun/autorun.sh
```

3. and use usfo users run apache
   apache2.conf:

```
User usfo
Group usfo
```

4. use this command run container

```
docker run -itd -p 80:80 --mount type=volume,source=sshvolume,destination=/swarm-data debian2
```

5. and I'm having trouble , only root users can access , usfo users can't not

```
root@e3ca660f3a8d:/# su root
root@e3ca660f3a8d:/# ls -l /swarm-data
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 usfo usfo 1136 Dec 26 02:37 Desktop.rar
-rw-r--r-- 1 usfo usfo    7 Dec 26 02:18 a.txt

root@e3ca660f3a8d:/# ls -l / | grep swarm-data
drwxr-x---   1 usfo usfo 4096 Dec 26 02:37 swarm-data
```

```
root@e3ca660f3a8d:/# su usfo
$ ls -l / |grep swarm-data
ls: cannot access '/swarm-data': Permission denied
d?????????   ? ?    ?       ?            ? swarm-data
```

6. Try not using vieux / sshfs , Is work! , **But  i have to use vieux/sshfs !!**

```
docker run -itd -p 80:80 -v  /swarm-study/web/data:/swarm-data debian2

root@d678cdb273c8:/# su usfo
$ ls -l / | grep swarm-data
drwxr-x---   2 usfo usfo 4096 Dec 26 10:54 swarm-data
```

docker Version:      17.09.1-ce

debian 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quote:https://github.com/vieux/docker-volume-sshfs/issues/17
Thank @koenlek

It turns out that you need to use the `-o allow_other` option of sshfs.

```
docker volume create  -d vieux/sshfs   -o sshcmd=usfo@192.168.1.1:/swarm-study/web/data  -o allow_other -o password='123' sshvolume
root@f5132a8f4b84:/# su usfo
$ ls -l / | grep swarm-data
drwxr-x---   1 usfo usfo 4096 Dec 26 10:54 swarm-data
```